# Javascript/NodeJS: html rendering before .find finishes inside forEach

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This loop is supposed to be checking for opps in the DB that match opps being pulled from the salesforce api results and then either creating a new opp or finding the existing opp and pushing it to the array. It seems that the res.render is running before the opp is found. It creates a new opp but the array returns empty when the page renders.

```
 Account.find({owner:req.user._id, prospect:'false'}).sort({ammount:'desc'}).populate({path: "notes", options:{ sort:{ 'date': -1 } } }).exec(function(err, allAccounts) {
        let callGoal = req.user.callGoal;
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }else{
            // if auth has not been set, redirect to index
            if (!req.session.accessToken || !req.session.instanceUrl) { res.redirect('/'); }
        //SOQL query
            let q = "SELECT Id,Amount,CloseDate,LastActivityDate,Name,StageName,account.Name FROM Opportunity WHERE CloseDate < 2018-10-01 AND OwnerId = '0050a00000J12PdAAJ' AND IsClosed = false AND StageName != 'Stage 6: Won'";
        //instantiate connection
            let conn = new jsforce.Connection({
                oauth2 : {oauth2},
                accessToken: req.session.accessToken,
                instanceUrl: req.session.instanceUrl
           });
        //set records array
            let softopps = [];
            let sfOpps = [];
            let query = conn.query(q)
               .on("record", function(record) {
                 sfOpps.push(record);
               })
               .on("end", function() {
                 console.log("total in database : " + query.totalSize);
                 console.log("total fetched : " + query.totalFetched);
                 let user = req.user;
                 sfOpps.forEach(function(sfopp){
                     if(err){
                         res.send(err);
                     }else{
                         Opp.findOne({sfid:sfopp.Id}).exec(function(err, opp){
                         if(!opp.length){
                            Opp.create(req.body, function(err, newOpp) {
                                if(err){
                                    res.send(err)
                                }else{
                                    newOpp.sfid = sfopp.Id;
                                    newOpp.name = sfopp.Name;
                                    newOpp.owner = user.sfid;
                                    newOpp.save();
                                    return softopps.push(newOpp)
                                }
                            })
                         }else{
                             return softopps.push(opp);
                         }
                     })
                     }
                 })
                 res.render("myaccounts", {accounts:allAccounts, callGoal:callGoal, user:user, sfOpps:sfOpps, opps:softopps});
               })
               .on("error", function(err) {
                 console.error(err);
               })
               .run({ autoFetch : true, maxFetch : 4000 });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Opp.findOne()` and `Opp.create()` calls are asynchronous, so they fire after the `res.render()`.

---

On the side, you pretty much kill your mongodb with all that unnecessary requests.

Try this logic instead (starting at `.forEach`)

1. Find all `Opp`s by ids of `sfOpps`
2. Figure out which `Opp`s were not found and create them
3. Concat all the found and not found `Opp`s
4. **Then, and only then** respond

I didn't test that code, but it can roughly give you an idea of what I mean

```
Opp.find({ sfid : { $in: sfOpps.map(opp => opp.id) } })
  .then(found => {

    const foundIds = found.map(opp => opp.sfid)
    const notFound = sfOpps.filter(opp => !foundIds.includes(opp.sfid)).map(sfopp => {
      return {
        sfid: sfopp.sfid,
        name: sfopp.name,
        owner: user.sfid
      }
    })

    Opp.insertMany(notFound)
      .then((insertResult) => {

        res.render("myaccounts", {
          accounts: allAccounts, 
          callGoal: callGoal, 
          user: user, 
          sfOpps: found.concat(notFound), 
          opps: softopps
        });

      }).catch(handleError)

  }).catch(handleError)
```

Comment: This worked great! Just had to make a couple adjustments (extra right-bracket on line 1, added an 's' to 'include' on line 4) and a few tweaks to handle the objects in the arrays. As a newbie to asyc concepts and es6 I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Pleasure is mine. As you go along, always do focus on querying your database as few times as possible :).

Comment: And, of course, thanks for pointing out my mistakes, I did fix them :)

Answer (score 0):

When the page rendered your still empty because the call of creation/find opps is an asynchronous but your page rendering is synchronous that's why your page rendered first before your calls will be complete.I think you should try to use async.eachOfSeries(coll, iteratee, callback) instead of sfOpps.forEach().

```
Account.find({owner:req.user._id, prospect:'false'}).sort({ammount:'desc'}).populate({path: "notes", options:{ sort:{ 'date': -1 } } }).exec(function(err, allAccounts) {
        let callGoal = req.user.callGoal;
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }else{
            // if auth has not been set, redirect to index
            if (!req.session.accessToken || !req.session.instanceUrl) { res.redirect('/'); }
        //SOQL query
            let q = "SELECT Id,Amount,CloseDate,LastActivityDate,Name,StageName,account.Name FROM Opportunity WHERE CloseDate < 2018-10-01 AND OwnerId = '0050a00000J12PdAAJ' AND IsClosed = false AND StageName != 'Stage 6: Won'";
        //instantiate connection
            let conn = new jsforce.Connection({
                oauth2 : {oauth2},
                accessToken: req.session.accessToken,
                instanceUrl: req.session.instanceUrl
           });
        //set records array
            let softopps = [];
            let sfOpps = [];
            let query = conn.query(q)
               .on("record", function(record) {
                 sfOpps.push(record);
               })
               .on("end", function() {
                 console.log("total in database : " + query.totalSize);
                 console.log("total fetched : " + query.totalFetched);
                 let user = req.user;
                 async.eachOfSeries(sfOpps,function(sfopp,next){
                     if(err){

                         next(err);
                     }else{
                         Opp.findOne({sfid:sfopp.Id}).exec(function(err, opp){
                         if(!opp.length){
                            Opp.create(req.body, function(err, newOpp) {
                                if(err){

                                    next(err);
                                }else{
                                    newOpp.sfid = sfopp.Id;
                                    newOpp.name = sfopp.Name;
                                    newOpp.owner = user.sfid;
                                    newOpp.save();
                                    softopps.push(newOpp);
                                    next();
                                }
                            })
                         }else{
                             softopps.push(opp);
                             next();

                         }
                     })
                     }
                 },function(err){
                  if (err) res.send(err);
                  else {
               res.render("myaccounts", {accounts:allAccounts, callGoal:callGoal, user:user, sfOpps:sfOpps, opps:softopps});
                     }
                    });
               })
               .on("error", function(err) {
                 console.error(err);
               })
               .run({ autoFetch : true, maxFetch : 4000 });
        }
    });
```

I hope this will help you.